# Google Drive API: Allows you to upload/download to users accounts or only your own?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a question about Google Drive that I'm hoping other programmers (with experience with the Google Drive API) will be able to answer. *Note I have consulted the Google Drive API faqs and example projects but they dont answer my question.* I'll provide some context in order for you to better understand my question.

We are developing an Smart Phone app that will allow people to view their civil engineering designs (Highway design, Dam design, Railway design, etc) in a 3d world, ie, showing their 'blue prints' in 3d. The app is being developed in Unity3d (3d Game Engine using C#).

Our plan is to create a Windows .exe (C# WinForms) that will allow the user to upload their blue print file to their own Google Drive account. The app will automatically download their blue prints from their google drive account (all the user has to do is login). *Why create a .exe to upload files to a users account and not just get them to do it themselves through a web browser? Because we want to make it easy for the user, eventually provide automatic uploads/updates (when the user edits their project) and ensure that the files will always be in a specific folder on google drive. Thus a .exe will be able to achieve this.*

**My Question:** Does the Google Drive API allow you to upload/download files to a users account. The Drive example projects appear to demonstrate uploading/downloading files to your own business Google Drive account and not a users. For those who have used the Google Drive API in their own projects; what are you charged for? Do you get charged for only downloading and uploading files or do you also get charge for connecting and querying files? If you upload/download files to an external Google Drive account (a users account) do you get charged or do they get charged?

Comment: Come on Google engineers, lol, this page says you monitor SO for these questions :P https://developers.google.com/drive/support

Answer (score 0):

If you have the users login to your app using Oauth2 they give you permission to access there google drive data.  They can then download and upload to there account from your app.

Here are a few tutoials i did on this topic. Its a popular question, im working on a few sample apps to go with it.

[Google Oauth2 c# Tutorial](http://daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/?rel=%27nofollow%27)

[Google Drive api C#](http://daimto.com/google-drive-api-c/?rel=nofollow)

```
 credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
          new ClientSecrets { ClientId = "YourClientId", ClientSecret = "YourClientSecret" },
          new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
            DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
          "user",
          CancellationToken.None,
           new SavedDataStore(myStoredResponse)).Result; }
```

Comment: @DalmTo thanks for the answer :) When the user download/uploads to their account from my app, do I get charged or them?

Comment: If you have the access token and the refresh token they granted to you from the app then you can access it.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for the answer. Do you have any solution to the same using PHP or Javascript. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are a few samples for upload and download on the repo  for php https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples